# Untraceable HTTP redirection?

Tags: javascript, python, http, redirect

I'm currently working on a project to track products from several websites. I use a python scraper to retrieve all the URLs related to the listed products, and later, regularly check if these URLs are still active.

To do so I use the Python requests module, run a get request and look at the response's status code. Usually I get **200**, **301**, **302** or **404** as expected, except in the following case:

http://www.sephora.fr/Parfum/Parfum-Femme/Totem-Orange-Eau-de-Toilette/P2232006

This product has been removed and while opening the link (sorry it's in French), I am briefly shown a placeholder page saying the product is not available anymore and then redirected to the home page (www.sephora.fr).

Oddly, Python still returns a **200** status code and so do various redirect tracers such as wheregoes.com or redirectdetective.com. The worst part is that the response URL still is the original, so I can't even trace it that way.

When analyzing with Chrome DevTools and preserving the logs, I see that at some point the page is reloaded. However I'm unable to find out where.

I'm guessing this is done client-side via Javascript, but I'm not quite sure how. Furthermore, I'd really need to be able to detect this change from within Python.

As a reference, here's a link to a working product:

http://www.sephora.fr/Parfum/Parfum-Femme/Kenzo-Jeu-d-Amour-Eau-de-Parfum/P1894014

Any leads?

Thank you !
Ludwig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has a [meta tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), that redirects the page to the root URL:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/" />
```

Comment: Then in addition to looking for a redirect, maybe the OP just just look for certain text saying the product doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks guys. Don't know why I hadn't seen this. 

I'm now using the **lxml** lib to filter the response content and search for such tags. Seems to work fine.